# Верно ли я понимаю принцип Less?

Tags: css, less

Всем привет.
less ведь полностью использует синтаксис css просто добавляет своих фишек типа переменные?, 
То есть я спокойно могу взять файл напр. bootstrap.css, поменять расширение с .css на .less и это будет полноценный less файл, который при компиляции опять же станет таким как прежде bootstrap.css и никакая инфа потеряна не будет?

P/S. 
Почему я спрашиваю?: Есть разные .css файлы(тот же бутстрап) и нужно как то это оптимизировать. 
То есть я решил переименовать все .css файлы в .less и командой import импортировать в один основной .less файл. 
Таким образом при компиляции этого одного основного .less он будет собирать все .css(.css файлы которые я переименовал в .less) в один файл.

Что бы еще яснее стало, вот этот основной .less файл:

```css
@import "var.less";
@import "mixins.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "fonts.less";

/* some less code... */
.h-top-panel {
  background-color: @dark_blue;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #323746;
  .h-tp-wrap {
    height: 89px;
  }
}
/* some less code... */

@import "media.less";
```

Answer (score 2):

> less ведь полностью использует синтаксис css просто добавляет своих фишек типа переменные?

Да, обратная совместимость с CSS поддерживается

> я решил переименовать все .css файлы в .less и командой import импортировать в один основной .less файл

Переименовывать для этого не обязательно. Команда import позволяет импортировать файлы с расширением `.css`

Но лучше сделать немного по-другому. Сначала скомпилировать less в css и только потом объёдинять и минимизировать (uglify) css-файлы.

Comment: "Переименовывать для этого не обязательно. Команда import позволяет импортировать файлы с расширением .css"
<br/>
Да, но мне не нужно подключать css файл мне нужны стили из него(что бы сократить количество http запросов).
1 файл в нем все стили без импорта других css фалов.